# how to find angle alpha in this equation

Tags: trigonometry

I need to calculate the angle $\alpha$ as a function of $A$, which is a constant. I have been looking at trigonometric equations to extract $\alpha$ out of the tan function, but could not find any. Any idea?
$$
A = \frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\pi\alpha}{180})} + \frac{\pi\alpha}{180}
$$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't solve this equation with a formula for $\alpha$. You will have to settle for numerical approximations.

You can ask [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%2010%20%3D%201%2F(tan(x))%20%2B%20x) to

```
solve 10 = 1/(tan(x)) + x
```

It shows a picture and some of the infinitely many solutions. One is

```
x ≈ -12.5219987254408
```

You can adjust for the $\pi/180$ yourself.